# Transparent Image Background Issue android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

Transparent Image background converts to Black Color After placing into Android Gallery. If I upload transparent image from gallery then the image background shows black color

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
    bitmap = eraseBG(bitmap, -1);         // use for white background
    bitmap = eraseBG(bitmap, -16777216);  // use for black background


private static Bitmap eraseBG(Bitmap src, int color) {
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap b = src.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    b.setHasAlpha(true);

    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        if (pixels[i] == color) {
            pixels[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    b.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Before adding your code, image is showing like this see the link https://ibb.co/cqPchJ
or
After Adding your code, image is showing like this see the link https://ibb.co/gwRb9y
Thanks for your help..

Comment: Use myImage.setAlpha(0); and upload

Comment: OR mComponentName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));